# Object Data type in c#

Tags: c#, object, visual-studio-2012, scope, boxing

I am facing a problem related to variable scope please suggest me a good solution for this problem.

Error: temp dose not exist in current context.

```
        if (cause_list_type_fk == 1)
        {
            Regularcause temp = (Regularcause) obj;
        }
        else if (cause_list_type_fk == 2)
        {
            urgentcauselist temp = (urgentcauselist) obj;
        }
        else 
        {
            supplementryTable temp = (supplementryTable)obj;
        }


            //
            // loging info to a file
            //
            using (StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"D:\log-entriesSupply.txt"))
            {
                string tmp = "-->Hearing id: " + hearing_id + "-->bench id: " + bench_id + "-->pary id: " + party_id + "\n";
                Log(tmp +  "-->case_id= " + case_id + "-->= " + temp.caseno + "-->temp.Id= " + temp.Id, w);
                w.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Which `temp` are you wanting to use? What have you researched?

Comment: What **type** is your variable `temp`? It is not clear and is also defined in the `if` block, not visible outside the block

Comment: i have to declare temp by checking the value of cause_list_type_fk. Is there any way to declare a variable in such a way ?

Comment: Yes, you have done. But do all 3 types have a `caseno`? do they all inherit from the same type? What have you researched?

Comment: You can inherit `supplementryTable`, `urgentcauselist` and `Regularcause` from the same interface if it is appropriate for you.

Comment: No all three types are different. but following code remain same for all the types that`s y i am trying to use one name and don`t want to replicate the code.

Comment: I believe you are talking about compile time error. 
for that declare object before your if condition.
& then use as object temp; a better way would be to use a common interface for the 3 objects

Comment: No, they are not all different. As @Andy stteted in his answer you havecommon properties and can put them in an interface which you will inherit your classes from.

Comment: these classes are auto generated by .net entity data model so if i implement interface is there any affect on the project ? ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you need to declare `temp` variable outside of `if` block, otherwise it will not be visible outside that block.

Second: from your code it looks like you're trying to use fields `caseno` and `Id` of your `temp`, but in your `if-else` conditions you're assigning objects of three different types `Regularcause`, `urgentcauselist` and `supplementryTable` to the same variable. Probably all of these types contains such a fields, but you can't do this in the manner you're trying to do.

Possible solution: create some interface, say

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    object caseno, Id
}
```

Of course, it should contain your actual field names and types. It is just a sample.

Make your classes `Regularcause`, `urgentcauselist` and `supplementryTable` implementing this interface.

And then declare your `temp` variable like

```
IMyInterface temp = obj as IMyInterface;
```

instead of your `if-else` block.

Comment: +1. Also, OP could just make a `Write(IMyInterface temp)` method that will remove the need to create the temp variable at all

Comment: these classes are auto generated by .net entity data model so if i implement interface is there any affect on the project ? ?

Comment: @wasipeer Are these generated classes `partial` ones? If yes - then you can add your own part to each class (in a separate file) and specify implementation of interface in this part. This will not affect the rest of generated class.